# javascript closing all other browser tabs or child tabs

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to close all other or child tabs in the browser window while keeping the first tab open. I want to do this with a JavaScript function call....Can anyone help?

All I can get is a function for closing the window.

Comment: You can only close tabs/windows that you open.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's nothing built-in to do this.

You get a handle to the other windows **you** have opened (when you call [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)). Keep all the handles from all the `window.open` calls in an array. Then, when you want to close all the child windows, iterate through the array and call [`Window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.close) on each element.